# Initialize struct using initializer list, fails for std::array

Tags: c++

I have a constructor of a struct taking one std::array, when I try to initialize using intializer list, it throws error
"Error  C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::vector>'

Similar to this,

```
struct Test
{
  int a, b, c, d;
  Test(array<int, 4>) { }
}

int main()
{
    vector<Test> Ar = { {1, 2, 3, 4} };
}
```

[Link on Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7206daaed2e682cd)

G++ throws error, error: could not convert '{{1, 2, 3, 4}}' from 'brace-enclosed initializer list' to 'std::vector'

EDIT: Yes, as per comments, adding two braces works. I can see, the outer brace is for member initialization, and the inner brake specifies initializer list for the array member.

This works -

```
int main()
{
  vector<Test> Ar = {
      { { 1, 2, 3, 4 } }
   };
}
```

Comment: you are mixing two things, what fails is not the creating of the struct, but the creation of a vector containing a struct. And please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `std::array` needs *two* pairs of braces.

Comment: btw your second example may compile, but `ValAr[15]` is out-of-bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be reduced to the following:

```
Test t = {1,2,3,4}; // error
```

Note it is `{1,2,3,4}` that can be converted to `std::array<int, 4>`, not `1,2,3,4`. So to initialize `Test`, you need two pairs of braces.

So in your code, to initialize a `vector` of `Test`, three pairs of braces are needed.